# Better Approach to successive dispatches?

Tags: reactjs, reducers

In React, I've generally created reducers to handle everything with one `dispatch`.  But there are some edge cases where I've done something like this:

```
dispatch({type: ADD_ERROR, payload: {name: 'vin', message, id}});
dispatch({type: UPDATE_VEHICLE_INFO, id, payload: ''});
```

It is true that I could expand the capabilities of `ADD_ERROR` to handle this edge case but it would be less obvious to a new developer.  So I'm not clear that making such a change is entirely a positive thing.

Also, would wrapping a component in `useMemo` solve the problem in such cases where multiple dispatches are used (with functional, not class components and where Context, not Redux is being used).

Comment: Is this dispatch from 'useReducer' ? also what is exactly the problem multiple re-renders ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami: Yes, the `dispatch` comes from `useReducer`.  We're using the same pattern as per Kent C. Dodds: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

My colleagues have suggested that multiple renders could become an issue.

In my reading, it is suggested that separating actions (and reducers) into logically different concerns is a good practice.

I wonder how difficult it would be to write a `batch` function that works with Context?

Answer (score 2):

React-Redux's [`batch()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) api allows you to batch together multiple actions.

**Example from their documentation**

```
import { batch } from 'react-redux'

function myThunk() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // should only result in one combined re-render, not two
    batch(() => {
      dispatch(increment())
      dispatch(increment())
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but, as I mentioned above, we're not use Redux.  Thus `batch` from `react-redux` has no applicability here.  If only there were an equivalent for Context.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question. React batches multiple state updates except when its called inside [Timeouts, promises, and async functions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-450167403), so you might want to double check if it's actually causing multiple rerenders. If it does cause rerenders, you could take a look at `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` api and create a hook from it.